# Increasing indent/margin for each li in a list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there an easy/elegant way in which to increasingly indent something using CSS?

Example, ul with five li and each one is 1 EM indented more than the one just above it? It seems like nth child could help but I'd like to keep support for IE8.

I know that I could assign IDs to each li but that doesn't seem very efficient...

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the [adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), but it's certainly not 'elegant'.

Comment: If you must support IE8 then there is no "efficient" way.

Comment: Even if you were to exclude IE8, there isn't an elegant way to do this.  You would have to write out a selector for each and every level of indentation you're planning to account for.  You could generate this programatically via a CSS preprocessor, but the results will be the same:  a big pile of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that can't be done with CSS alone cleanly.

You'll have to leverage JavaScript, loop through the `li`s and calculate the indentation for each.